# How to pass multiple parameters to MVC controller including list/array of strings?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a ajax call and I'm trying to post an array of strings, as well as an id and search parameter to a controller.  Anyone able to show me how to do this?
Example:

***jQuery***

```
$("body").on("click", "#btnClientModalSearch", function (e) {
    preventDefaultAction(e);
    var url = GetUrlPath() + "/Client/GetClientCalendarSearchResults";
    var searchTypeId = $("#ddlSearchType").val();
    var searchParameter = $("#tbSearchParameter").val();
    var diaryId = $("#SelectedEventId").val();
    var values = [];
    $(".referralIdList").each(function () {
        var referralId = $(this).attr("id");
        var arr = referralId.split('referralId');
        values.push(arr[1]);
    });
    var postData = { alreadyAddedReferralIds: values };
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { searchTypeId: searchTypeId, searchParameter: searchParameter, diaryId: diaryId, alreadyAddedReferralIds: postData },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success === true) {
                $("#searchResultsPlaceHolder").html(result.view);
            }
        },
        error: function (responseText, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

***Controller***

```
 public JsonResult GetClientCalendarSearchResults(string searchTypeId, string searchParameter, string diaryId, List < string > alreadyAddedReferralIds) {}
```

When I try this, the *alreadyAddedReferralIds* is always empty at the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the parameters in the controller with a single object parameter. So you would have something like:

```
public JsonResult GetClientCalendarSearchResults(SearchResultsRequest request)

public class SearchResultRequest
{
   public string searchTypeId { get; set; } 
   public string searchParameter { get; set; } 
   public string diaryId { get; set; } 
   public List<string> alreadyAddedReferralIds { get; set; }
}
```

From my experience posting to an action method that requires multiple parameters won't have their values populated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're passing `alreadyAddedReferralIds` as an object. It should be an array instead. Try this:

```
var values = $(".referralIdList").map(function () {
    return this.id.split('referralId')[1];
}).get();

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: { 
        searchTypeId: searchTypeId, 
        searchParameter: searchParameter, 
        diaryId: diaryId, 
        alreadyAddedReferralIds: values // note: passing the array directly
    },
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.success) {
            $("#searchResultsPlaceHolder").html(result.view);
        }
    },
    error: function (responseText, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Also note the use of `map()` to create your array instead of `each()`.

Comment: Didn't work, the List<string> alreadyAddedReferralIds on the controller is still null, but there's definitely values in the array on the jquery end of things.  I've also have the parameter type on the controller as string[] alreadyAddedReferralIds, didn't make a difference, still null.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'controller/myaction',
   dataType: "json",
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   traditional: true,
   data: JSON.stringify({
      myKey: myArray
   }),
   success: function(data) { /* Whatever */ }
});
```